# Not model based Django auth

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am learning Django auth at the moment and it looks great!
However it came to my attention that it seems a little bit too model-based.

What I think of is that let's say I have two web pages (monitoring, statistics) and they both use the same model (event table). What I want is to add permission to different users to access monitoring and to statistics, like: can_use_monitoring, can_use_statistics.
I presume it is not a problem to add the same model to these 2 permissions but seems unnecessary and misleading. Or am I missing something?

How would you achieve that?

Thanks,
V.

/////// UPDATE /////////
One thought: what I would want is to have permission based on the web pages and not on models. It is possible that one page uses more models and I wouldn't know which model should I assign to the permission (as I can only one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I presume it is not a problem to add the same model to these 2 permissions but seems unnecessary and misleading. Or am I missing something?

Yes there is no problem adding the same model to different permissions.

Typically you should use [Django's Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#groups) feature. Make a group which has a bundle of permissions and then keep adding users to the group.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

> One thought: what I would want is to have permission based on the web pages and not on models. It is possible that one page uses more models and I wouldn't know which model should I assign to the permission (as I can only one).

This is made possible by using decorating your view with the `user_passes_test` or `permission_required` decorators. [More here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)

eg

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
@user_passes_test(email_check)
def my_view(request):
    ...

def email_check(user):
    return user.email.endswith('@example.com')
```

Comment: Thanks Nosh for the reply! I think based on the answer there is no other way but starting from the model. How would you handle the case I mentioned in the UPDATE section of my original question (having two page, using the same model)? Just add a 'can_use_monitoring' permission and choose one of the models that is used?

Comment: Yes, if you want to manage the user using the django permissions api. The convention is to use the most important model in the group you are dealing with. Or you could simply use `user_passes_test ` and pass in a custom function. eg: a function to check if the user belongs to a group like `system-admins`.